# Inserts duplicate entry when you insert arrayed data (KNEXJS and SQLITE3)

Tags: database, sqlite, knex.js

My code for inserting multiple entries in the database is like this:

```
let model = [
        {
            Question: '1 + 1',
            QuestionTypeId: 1,
            Answer: '2',
            QuizId: 1,
            Options: null
        },
        {
            Question: '1 + 2',
            QuestionTypeId: 1,
            Answer: '3',
            QuizId: 1,
            Options: null
        }
    ]
    let result = knex('Items').insert(model)
```

but it inserts the data twice on the database like this

[image]

Can somebody explain to me why it inserts 2 more rows on the database? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you pasted in question actually does not insert anything (query builder is never triggered).

Knex does not insert the data twice unless you tell it to insert it twice. Maybe in the code that you have not show in question you are calling `.then()` twice for the query builder stored in variable `result`.

This may work better:

```
let model = [
    {
        Question: '1 + 1',
        QuestionTypeId: 1,
        Answer: '2',
        QuizId: 1,
        Options: null
    },
    {
        Question: '1 + 2',
        QuestionTypeId: 1,
        Answer: '3',
        QuizId: 1,
        Options: null
    }
];

let result = await knex('Items').insert(model);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just added the await and async. Now its working. Thanks very much :)